# jQuery function used as event handler and for initialization

Tags: javascript, initialization, jquery

I'm doing this over and over, and I'm not sure if it is the best way to do so in JavaScript/jQuery. I have a function that acts as an event handler, but also I need to call it on page initialization. Thus I have been using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        function doToggle() {
            $("#toggle-fields").toggle(!$('#checkToggle').is(':checked'));
        }
        doToggle();

        $('#checkToggle').click(doToggle);
    });
</script>
```

How do you tackle this repetitious situation? Are there any best practices that you can point me toward?

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: I don't see any repetition there.

Comment: Sorry, was a little too fast with my cut-and-paste, the code I originally put up would not actually work. Concept is still the same though.

Comment: @DavGarcia - so was I, with your code :)

Comment: @DavGarcia - does your initialization and handler code *always/only* manipulate DOM elements as in above example?

Comment: Yes, that is right. If it does something else like call a REST service for some external data, it is only to use that data to manipulate its DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is :)

```
$('#checkToggle').click(doToggle).click();
```

Comment: Note that this will also trigger other handlers.

Comment: @SLaks - that's true, but I'm thinking of this from a UI perspective. Put the application in an initial state that it would be in *if* the element was clicked (which means all attached handlers will indeed run).

Comment: Good idea.  However, if he has non-idempotent handlers, he should be aware of that.

Comment: @Reigel - Namespacing is definitely not a bad idea at all. In fact, it is a very good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Your code will not work because `this` will be `window` in the first call.

Change it to

```
doToggle.call(document.getElementByID('checkToggle'));
```

Answer (score 2):

like this...

```
$(function() {
    $('#checkToggle').bind('click.toggle',function(){
        $("#toggle-fields").toggle(!this.checked);
    }).trigger('click.toggle');
});
```